# how to get radio button value using jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

```
<input id="user_type_local" type="radio" checked="true" value="local" name="data[user_type]">
Local
<input id="user_type_sso" type="radio" value="sso" name="data[user_type]">
Gilead SSO
```

How can we get the value of checked radio button using jQuery? I tried

```
 $('input[name=data[user_type]]:radio').val();
```

But it does not work.

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=data[user_type]]:radio

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `id` attribute? `$( "#user_type_sso" ).val()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wrap string in quotes:

```
$('input[name="data[user_type]"]:radio').val();
```

Which is the same as using double escape:

```
$('input[name=data\\[user_type\\]]:radio').val();
```

Answer (score 3):

`[` and `]` are [meta-characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), you have to escape it, or you can simply make that as a string.

Try,

```
$('input[name="data[user_type]"][type="radio"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:radio[name=theme]").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
});
```